# Swift 4.2 imagePickerController issue

Tags: swift, uiimagepickercontroller, swift4.2

Trying to pass chat client from swift 4 to swift 4.2 and with picker i found trouble.

> UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage Cannot subscript a value of type
>   '[String : Any]' with an index of type
>   'UIImagePickerController.InfoKey'

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

    if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
        self.userProfileImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        self.userProfileImage.image = pickedImage
    }

    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The method signature has changed to

`func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])`

You should see a warning message for the func name

> Instance method
>   'imagePickerController(*:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)' nearly
>   matches optional requirement
>   'imagePickerController(*:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)' of protocol
>   'UIImagePickerControllerDelegate'
>
> Candidate has non-matching type '(UIImagePickerController, [String :
>   Any]) -> ()'
>
> Move 'imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)' to
>   another extension to silence this warning
>
> Make 'imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)' private
>   to silence this warning
>
> Requirement 'imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:)'
>   declared here (UIKit.UIImagePickerControllerDelegate)

Comment: and ->    let image = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage

Answer (score 10):

In Swift 4.2 imagePickerController delegate methods has changed a bit. Kindly check out the below code.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

    var selectedImage: UIImage?
    if let editedImage = info[.editedImage] as? UIImage {
        selectedImage = editedImage
        self.profileImage.image = selectedImage!
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else if let originalImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        selectedImage = originalImage
        self.profileImage.image = selectedImage!
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

This will work for sure.

Comment: I would move self.profileImage.image = selectedImage!
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) outside of 'if/else' statement.

Comment: @Paragon yes you can "picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)" put this out of the condition. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

like this

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage]! as! UIImage
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift4.2

```
 //MARK:- ImagePicker Controller Delegate
 //MARK:-

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    if let chosenImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
        yourimage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        yourimage.image = chosenImage

    } else{
        print("Something went wrong")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {

        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
            yourImage.image = pickedImage
        }else{
            print("Something went wrong!!")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extension CameraViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let chosenImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            selectedImage = chosenImage
            photo.image = chosenImage
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Above code solved the warning and image successfully uploaded

Comment: Please edit the answer to use a plain text code block instead of an image of code.